# Select statement takes long time to executing the results for a big table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table called

```
ER_GL (BUILDID, EYEAR, TTYPE, PID, ICAT, SDATE, LNUM, AMOUNT, ORGID, ETC.)
```

When I just `select * from ER_GL` without a where condition, it takes 3 minutes to return the results. This table has a primary key unique index on `(BUILDID, EYEAR, TTYPE, PID, ICAT, SDATE, LNUM)`.

How to improve the performance for the above table? Adding more indexes or in any other way could I make it better to get results in seconds?

Also, the below query again takes more and more time to return the results due to the impact of the above large table. Some articles mentioned that I can use `Cross join` instead of `Inner Join`. Can someone guide me to refactor the below SQL query and explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
SELECT 
    S.EYEAR,
    S.BUILDID,
    GETDATE(),
    SUM(G.AMOUNT), 
    (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(AMOUNT,0))
     FROM ER_GL X
     WHERE X.BUILDID = @XBUILDID
       AND X.EYEAR = @XEYEAR
       AND Y.TTYPE = 'A'
       AND X.PID = S.PID 
       AND X.ICAT = @XICAT 
       AND X.SDATE BETWEEN S.EDATE AND MAX(S.ENDDATE)),
    (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(AMOUNT,0))
     FROM ER_GL Y
     WHERE Y.BUILDID = @XBUILDID
       AND Y.EYEAR = @XEYEAR2
       AND Y.TTYPE = 'A' 
       AND Y.PID = S.PID 
       AND Y.ICAT = @XICAT
       AND Y.SDATE BETWEEN S.EDATE AND MAX(S.ENDDATE)),
    G.ORGID
FROM 
    #TEMP_CALC (NOLOCK) S
INNER JOIN 
    ER_GL G ON G.BUILDID = S.BUILDID 
            AND G.EYEAR = S.EYEAR AND G.TTYPE = 'A' 
            AND G.PID = S.PID 
            AND G.ICAT = S.ICAT 
            AND G.SDATE BETWEEN S.EDATE AND S.ENDDATE
WHERE 
    S.BUILDID = @XBUILDID 
    AND S.ICAT = @XICAT
    AND S.EYEAR = @XEYEAR
GROUP BY 
    S.BUILDID, S.ICAT, S.EYEAR, S.PID, S.EFFDATE, G.ORGID
ORDER BY 
    S.PID, S.EFFDATE
```

Comment: Don't pay any attention to somebody telling you to start using cross joins.

Comment: `NOLOCK` against a temporary table? *What*? ***Why***? Who is going to be using that temporary table other than you?

Comment: Are `S.BUILDID` `S.ICAT` and  `S.EYEAR` indexed?

Comment: I think you've confused the purposes of `where` and `on`

Comment: Inspect, and post, the execution plan

Comment: @zak No it's not indexed at the moment.

Comment: Indexing items that appears in your `WHERE` statement will greatly improve the query speed ..  Especially on a large database ..

Comment: You need to only ask about 1 query per question either `select * ...` or your more complex one, not both

Comment: Sorry @DaleK The second one is my actual question and the top one is impacting the second one. Sorry and I make sure will post it separately next time.

Comment: I suggest investing the time to learn and understand SQL performance. Otherwise you will be dependent on asking for help every time you have performance issues

Comment: I tried and spent time on YouTube and google to use the SQL trace and profiler and how to use the Execution plan but still learning.

Comment: Can you [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: @zak Where Clause is based on a temp table. Can we make an index for temp tables?

Comment: The object aliased as `S` appears to be missing from your query; that query won't run.

Comment: Thanks @ThomA I think this is what you asked? (I have updated the question)

Comment: I didn't ask for the time and IO statistics for a completely different query, @Sri, no.

Comment: Oh *wow*, the (ab)use of `NOLOCK` is strong with this one. Why *are* you littering your queries that hint? You do understand what it does, I assume?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that clear outs the table deadlock

Comment: Highly recommended reading: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: There's actually a surprising number of seeks there, so indexing does appear to at least be relevant; a surprise to be sure, but a welcome one. The subqueries, in the `SELECT` could well the the issue, which the answer below covers l

Comment: @Sri yes you can --> `create nonclustered index idx on #table (field)`  Keep in mind is will be a NON PK index ..

Comment: That index could do with an `INCLUDE`, @Zak .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can refactor this to use conditional aggregation. It's hard to see exactly what you need without proper sample data and expected results, but something like this should work.

```sql
SELECT
  S.EYEAR,
  S.BUILDID,
  GETDATE(),
  SUM(G.AMOUNT) AS BothYears,
  SUM(CASE WHEN G.SDATE BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(@XEYEAR, 1, 1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(@XEYEAR + 1, 1, 1) THEN G.AMOUNT END) AS FirstYear,
  SUM(CASE WHEN G.SDATE BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(@XEYEAR2, 1, 1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(@XEYEAR2 + 1, 1, 1) THEN G.AMOUNT END) AS SecondYear,
  G.ORGID
FROM #TEMP_CALC S
JOIN ER_GL G
   ON G.BUILDID = S.BUILDID 
  AND G.EYEAR IN (@XEYEAR, @XEYEAR2)
  AND G.TTYPE = 'A' 
  AND G.PID = S.PID 
  AND G.ICAT = S.ICAT 
  AND G.SDATE BETWEEN S.EDATE AND S.ENDDATE
WHERE S.BUILDID = @XBUILDID 
  AND S.ICAT = @XICAT
  AND S.EYEAR = @XEYEAR
GROUP BY
  S.BUILDID,
  S.ICAT,
  S.EYEAR,
  S.PID,
  S.EFFDATE,
  G.ORGID
ORDER BY
  S.PID,
  S.EFFDATE;
```

Avoid `NOLOCK`, it's the work of the devil, and it makes no sense on temp tables anyway. Exactly why you are using a temp table is also unclear.

The following index would probably be best:

```
#TEMP_CALC (BUILDID, ICAT, EYEAR, PID, EFFDATE)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely the nested `SELECT` queries back into the large table. You're likely much better off re-writing this so the existing `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` expressions keep ALL of the potential rows from the subqueries, with extra rows rolled up as members of the appropriate groups. Then use **conditional aggregation** to show the exact values within each group you need.

This will reduce you from currently a minimum of three passes through the large table — more likely one base plus two additional inspections **per result row!** — down to potentially just one pass total. You *may* need to do a JOIN from the table to itself, to get the `Y` values for corresponding `X` starting points. In this case you would still have probably two inspections of the large table, but that would still be a meaningful improvement.